# Can't convert from T to Integer

Tags: java, generics

I already tried some things with Java generics, but this problem seems to be impossible to solve!

Because of abstract superclasses I have to implement a method adding two values of Type T if they are Integer and return a result of type T.

```
public T evaluate(T left, T right) {
    if(left instanceof Integer && right instanceof Integer){
        return (((Integer)left) + ((Integer)right));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

That's  all i did so far, because Eclipse always tells me, that Java can't convert from Integer to T.

How can I force Java to convert to T?
Or is there a possibility to write two methods? One for T extending Integer and one for not?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Note that if `left` is `Integer` then you cannot use an `evaluate` method since this method doesn't exist in `Integer` class.

Comment: Sorry, it was:

public T evaluate(T left, T right) {
    if(left instanceof Integer && right instanceof Integer){
        return (((Integer)left) + ((Integer)right));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

Comment: On top of what Luiggi says: `(Integer)left.evaluate()` this will first execute `evaluate()` and then cast the result. That's impossible, since `T` has no knowledge about its class at that point.

Comment: What is the method declaration in the abstract superclass? Add it to the question.

Comment: Add the abstract class signature as well please

Comment: Does anyone else have an issue with the violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle? I feel like the question is about a symptom when the disease could be a poor inheritance model.

Comment: *" adding two values of Type T if they are Integer and return a result of type T"* What is the point of using generics?  Just make the method take arguments of type Integer and return and Integer.  You just stated you will know what the argument types are and the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns `T`, so you need to cast your result to `T`. For example:

```
  public T evaluate(T left, T right) {
    if (left instanceof Integer && right instanceof Integer) {
      Integer result = ((Integer) left) + ((Integer) right);
      return (T) result;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Then there is only a warning beacause of Type safety.
Why do I need to use this workaround? casting 
((T)((Integer) left) + ((Integer) right)) 
does not help

Comment: You can suppress the warning if you like with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Doing the cast like in your comment doesn't work because it can't cast a primitive (`int`) to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Generics seem to be not needed in this case, because the method `evaluate()` only deals with one specific type (`Integer`) and returns that specific type (again, `Integer`)

Comment: He clarified in the comments that `.evaluate()` didn't belong there.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenVannevel - It could have been some `my.Integer` :)

Comment: @Raffaele I edited your answer because I think the second half was spot-on advice.